# vba removing duplicates from new set

Tags: excel, vba

The code below creates a new set of data on a new sheet but it takes everything that matches the requirements even if it is a duplicate. How can I change the code to eliminate duplicates in the new data set?

```css
Sub Testerss()
    Dim c As Range, v As String, arr, x As Long, e
    Dim d As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet

  
    Set d = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D1")

    For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("D25:D105")
        v = Trim(c.Value)
        If Len(v) > 0 Then

            v = Replace(v, vbLf, " ")
            
            Do While InStr(v, "  ") > 0
                v = Replace(v, "  ", " ")
            Loop

            
            arr = Split(v, " ")
            For x = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
                e = arr(x)
                
                If Not IsError(Application.Match(LCase(e), Array("(bye)", "(hello)"), 0)) Then
                    If x > LBound(arr) Then
                        d.Value = arr(x - 1) & " " & e
                    Else
                        d.Value = "??? " & e
                    End If
                    Set d = d.Offset(1, 0)
                End If
            Next x
        End If
   Next c
End Sub​
```

Comment: [Range.RemoveDuplicates()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193823.aspx) may be of use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a check to see if the result has already been copied over. First set a range of the results

```
finalRow = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1000000, 4).end(xlup).row
Set resultRange = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D1:D" & finalRow)
```

Now see if the value you are currently examining is in that range

```
duplicate = false
for each result in resultRange
    if v = result.Value then
        duplicate = true
        Exit For
    end if
next
```

Now also check for duplicate before proceeding

```
If Len(v) > 0 and not duplicate then
```

All together

```
Set d = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D1")

For Each c In ActiveSheet.Range("D25:D105")
    finalRow = Worksheets("Sheet3").Cells(1000000, 4).end(xlup).row
    Set resultRange = Worksheets("Sheet3").Range("D1:D" & finalRow)
    v = Trim(c.Value)
    duplicate = false
    for each result in resultRange
        if v = result.Value then
            duplicate = true
            Exit For
        end if
    next

    If Len(v) > 0 and not duplicate then

    ...
```

Comment: I tried your code but it just continues what it did before and doesn't remove the duplicates.

Comment: I made an edit that I think will help. Is the code as it stands currently different than what you tried that I posted before?

Comment: Seems like it should work. You can try `If Len(v) > 0 and duplicate=false` instead to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Thanks for the help nonetheless. I'll let you know if I can get it to work.